# При попытке добавить объект в ArrayList,возникает ошибка "non-static variable luis cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, ооп, arraylist, static

В классе Loc есть конструктор:

```
public Loc(){
     ArrayList<Person> inloc = new ArrayList<Person>(3);
     inloc.add(Luis.luis);
     System.out.println(inloc.get(0).name);
 }
```

Код класса Luis выглядит так:

```
public class Luis extends Person {
    public Luis luis = new Luis("Luis");

    public Luis(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:  java: non-static variable luis cannot be referenced from a static context

Расскажу, как я понимаю, что происходит: В конструкторе Loc я вполне успешно создаю ArrayList объектов класса Person, наследником которого является и Luis.

Затем при попытке добавить объект класса Luis к ArrayList появляется ошибка, которая намекает, что объект - нестатический, а конструктор статический (честно говоря, не знаю, так ли это, в явном виде нигде в программе это не пишется)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как верно указал @insolor в своём ответе, *данная* ошибка возникла из-за попытки обратиться к нестатическому полю через имя класса `Luis.luis`, что допустимо только для статических полей.

Также следует отметить, что если закомментировать вызов `Luis.luis`, то указанная ошибка пропадёт, но код, представленный в классе `Luis`, останется не рабочим из-за циклического вызова конструктора и неопределенного поля `name`:

```java
public class Luis extends Person {
    public Luis luis = new Luis("Luis"); // !!! так нельзя делать

    public Luis(String n) {
        this.name = n;  // следует вызвать конструктор класса-родителя
    }
}
```

При вызове `new Luis("luis")` будет инициализироваться нестатическое поле `luis` такого же типа `Luis`, то есть снова будет создаваться экземпляр `new Luis("luis")`, со своим нестатическим полем, для которого снова вызовется конструктор `new Luis("luis")` и так до переполнения стека `StackOverflowError`.

Решение данной проблемы состоит в объявлении поля `luis` статическим, как показано в ответе @insolor, тогда зацикливания не будет, конструктор для статического поля будет вызван только один раз.

Если цель создания класса `Luis` -- создать *только один экземпляр с именем `"luis"`*, то конструктор следует сделать приватным:

```java
public class Luis extends Person {
    public static Luis luis = new Luis("Luis");

    private Luis(String n) {
        super(n); // если в классе Person есть соответствующий конструктор
    }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо,я действительно сглупил вызывая luis через класс,я переживал,что он в другом классе...

В Luis,как вы и указали, я не планирую создавать больше объектов,однако не потеряю ли я в будущем возможности использования этого объекта(вызывать у него нестатические методы например, или что-то еще? (просто я впервые вижу создание static экземпляра, не знаю чего от него ожидать)

Comment: И еще вопрос,что изменится,если я буду создавать luis в методе main?

Comment: _если я буду создавать luis в методе main_ Если нестатическое поле `Luis luis` оставить в классе `Luis`, то нельзя будет создать экземпляр такого класса из-за зацикливания, как я описал выше в ответе.  Если же это поле убрать полностью или сделать статическим -- проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: _не потеряю ли я в будущем возможности использования этого объекта_ -- если у вас создан объект-одиночка (синглтон), вам следует помнить об этом, если вы вдруг добавите такой объект в коллекцию/массив, так как фактически будет создано несколько _ссылок_ на один и тот же объект, что может также привести к нежелательным побочным эффектам, если потребуется изменить некие поля в данном экземпляре `luis`.

Comment: Всем спасибо за разъяснения!

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка

> non-static variable luis cannot be referenced from a static context
> (нельзя обратиться к не-статической переменной из статического контекста)

возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к нестатическому полю через имя класса: `Luis.luis`. К нестатическим полям можно обращаться только через созданный объект, условно, `new Luis("qwert").luis`.

Намеков на то, что объект не статический никаких нет, явно написано про не статическое поле. "Статический контекст" в данном случае означает попытку обращения через имя класса.

Чтобы к полю можно было обратиться через класс, нужно объявить его статическим:

```
public class Luis extends Person {
    public static Luis luis = new Luis("Luis");

    public Luis(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }
}
```